# Pass a parameter to a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, jquery

I have a web service, the code:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool ValidateUserName()
    {
        string UserNameCreated = TextUserName.Text; // textbox string to be passed.
```

How can I pass a textbox control's value TextUserName.Text to it?
I am going to do a jquery ajax call this web method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should retrieve the textbox's value within your javascript and then pass the string as a method parameter.

```
[WebMethod]
public bool ValidateUserName(String username)
{
    string UserNameCreated = username; // textbox string to be passed.
}
```

Comment: @Love: You need any help to retrieve the TextBox's value using javascript or jQuery?